# Configure Amazon SQS queue name in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-sqs, spring-cloud-aws

I'm using AmazonSQS & Spring Boot (spring-cloud-aws-messaging). I've configured a message listener to receive messages from the queue with the annotation @SqsListener.

```
@SqsListener(value = "indexerQueue", deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS)
public void queueListener(String rawMessage) {
   ...
}
```

This is a very simple approach but I didn't find the way to make the queue name load from a configuration file because I have different environments. Any ideas on this regard?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

What version of `spring-cloud-aws-messaging` are you using? Version 1.1 should allow you to use a placeholder as a queue name, e.g.

```
@SqsListener(value = "${sqs.queue.indexer}", deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS)
public void queueListener(String rawMessage) {
   ...
}
```

Then, in your application-**env**.properties files you can put different values. For instance in **application-dev.properties**:

```
sqs.queue.indexer=devIndexerQueue
```

and in **application-production.properties**

```
sqs.queue.indexer=indexerQueue
```

Comment: how can we set the name if using properties file is not an option? We use CloudFoundry and the name can only be fetch using CfEnv at startup time

Comment: You could perhaps use an ApplicationContextInitialiser to populate the Environment with the properties, or, even better, use OS env vars - in this case setting SQS_QUEUE_INDEXER should do the trick